# Reading data in Matlab from a large textfile

Tags: matlab, import, text-files

I have a text file containing a large number of rows of data with columns separated by spaces. How can I read in this data with MATLAB? I have tried the following code without success:

```
fid = fopen('file.txt');

M = textscan(fid, '%f %f %f');

x = M{1};

y = M{2};

z = M{3};
```

The data is as shown below (the columns are not equally spaced):

```
4.55686    0.88751    4.71368       0.00000       0.00000   879.7   0.143   1.77  1  1  Iron - Alpha

4.55686    0.88751    4.71368       0.00000       0.00000   879.7   0.143   1.77  1  1  Iron - Alpha

4.55686    0.88751    4.71368       0.00000       0.00000   879.7   0.143   1.77  1  1  Iron - Alpha

4.55686    0.88751    4.71368       0.00000       0.00000   879.7   0.143   1.77  1  1  Iron - Alpha

4.55686    0.88751    4.71368       0.00000       0.00000   879.7   0.143   1.77  1  1  Iron - Alpha

4.55686    0.88751    4.71368       0.00000       0.00000   879.7   0.143   1.77  1  1  Iron - Alpha
```

Comment: Can you specify what "unable" means?

Comment: matlab is not taking the data columnwise but arbitrarily from different columns.

Comment: open a notepad and replace all spaces with ";" in one action !

Comment: Have you tried the Import Wizard ?  It's often the easiest approach especially if you are not familiar with Matlab's more sophisticated (and correspondingly more difficult) alternatives.  Activate it either by selecting File | Import Data from the menu, or by evaluating `uiimport` at the command line.

Comment: yes I have tried import data...but it is not able to differentiate into different columns.I have also tried replacing the spaces with semicolons

Comment: I'm very surprised at your previous comment.  Can you add some of the lines from your input file into your question ?  Do different rows contain different numbers of columns ?

Comment: Ahh, now we can see some of your file.  Which columns do you want to read into Matlab ?

Comment: the first 5 columns....but when I do the 'import data' matlab considers the entire data as a single column i.e nx1 matrix....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, consider your data file.  Each line contains 10 numbers and 3 strings.  It would be easy to think that it contains 10 numbers and 1 string, but since a space is used as a delimiter and the characters `Iron - Alpha` are not enclosed in quotation marks they make 3 strings, not 1.

Next, `textscan` will only behave itself as you wish if you provide a complete description of the input line in the format specification.  For example, the following

```
 M = textscan(fid, '%f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %s %s %s')
```

works just fine for me.  Since you only want the first 5 columns of data, and this reads all the data, you can easily delete the unwanted columns.

If you want or need to avoid reading the unwanted data you'll have to get a little smarter.  You can instruct `textscan` to ignore specific fields like this:

```
 M = textscan(fid, '%f %f %f %f %f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*s %*s %*s')
```

which reads only the first 5 fields in each line.  The documentation will point you towards ways of refining your reading routine even further.

Comment: Nope still no result                                                              ??? Error using ==> dlmread at 145
Mismatch between file and format string.
Trouble reading number from file (row 1, field 30) ==> Iron

Error in ==> gnd11 at 1
fid = dlmread('test.txt',' ');

Comment: fid = dlmread('test.txt');
A =  textscan(fid, '%f %f %f %f %f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*s %*s %*s') ;
x = A{1};
y = A{2};
z = A{3};
e = A{4};
f = A{5};

Comment: Line 1: `fid = fopen('file.txt')`.  You obviously haven't read the documentation for `dlmread`.  I suggest you do so, and the documentation for `textscan`.

Comment: one more question....if my file has 6 lines of headers which I dont want to read and the data starts from the 7th line, can you tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Please try dlmread.

```
data = dlmread('file.txt');
```

And check if the separator is space. It may contain invisible char '\t'.

Comment: ??? Error using ==> dlmread at 145
Mismatch between file and format string.

Error in ==> abc at 1
fid = dlmread('test2.txt','\t');

Comment: Evidence that there are irregularities in your input file.  You might make headway by fixing those irregularities before trying to import the file.

Comment: isn't there any other way? Since my data sets are generated automatically and there are generally around half a million rows. So its practically impossible for me to change them

Comment: Now that we've seen sample input data, we can see that `dlmread`, which works only on numeric data, is not the right function for this.